# AngularFire2 Join two collections together

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have two data collections

```
Collection1 = Companies (List of companies)
ID
..

Collection2 = TH(List of summary Transaction History)
ID
```

Essentially they both have the same ID (company-ID) and I am trying to merge each company with its companion record in (TH) and then be able to output that onto a table.

Googling a lot, but its not helping.

My Code (companies.services.ts)

---

```
 export class CompanieService {

 companiesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection <Company>;
 thv4CLcollection: AngularFirestoreCollection <THv4CL>;

 Thv4: AngularFirestoreDocument <THv4CL>;

 companies: Observable<Company[]>;  
 Thv4C: Observable<any[]>;


 constructor(public fs: AngularFirestore) { 
   this.companiesCollection = fs.collection<Company>('companies', ref =>               
   ref.orderBy('companyName'));

   this.thv4CLcollection= fs.collection<THv4CL>('transactionHistory', ref => 
   ref.orderBy('companyName'));



//const res = await Promise.all(clients);

   this.companies = this.companiesCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
     map(actions => actions.map(a => {
       var data = a.payload.doc.data() as Company;
       const id = a.payload.doc.id;

       this.fs.doc('transactionHistory/' + id).valueChanges().pipe(
         map(data2 =>
         Object.assign({}, {
           id, ...data, ...data2
          })));

    return { id, ...data };
  }))
);
  }
```

---

I also tried

```
this.companiesCollection = fs.collection<Company>('companies', ref =>     
ref.orderBy('companyName'));
this.companies = this.companiesCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Company;
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
   // console.log("company "+data.companyName);


this.fs.collection<THv4CL>("transactionHistory").doc(data.identifier)
 .snapshotChanges().pipe(       map(data2 =>
        {
          console.log("Thv4CL "+data2);

          data.thCL=data2.payload.data() as THv4CL;

      }));

    return { id, ...data,  };
  }))
);
```

I tried iterating through and get back a list of all the companies but not joined with the other collection.